# Group array within group data php

Tags: php, arrays, grouping

After generating group array from an associative array, now the array is in the following format. And to make this group array I have used the following code:

```
foreach($upcoming_data_arr as $key => $item)
        {
            $arr[$item['year']][$key] = $item;
        } 

Array
(
    [2018] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 6
                    [year] => 2018
                    [month] => 11
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 5
                    [year] => 2018
                    [month] => 12
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [year] => 2018
                    [month] => 11
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [year] => 2018
                    [month] => 11
                )
        )
)
```

Now I need another group array according to month within year group. And in this case group data array will be like following:

```
 Array
    (
        [2018] => Array
            (
                [11] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                            [id] => 6
                            [year] => 2018
                            [month] => 11
                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                            [id] => 4
                            [year] => 2018
                            [month] => 11
                            )

                        [2] => Array
                           (
                            [id] => 3
                            [year] => 2018
                            [month] => 11
                            )

                    )

                [12] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                           (
                           [id] => 5
                           [year] => 2018
                           [month] => 12
                           )
                    )
            )
    )
```

How we will get this output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add one more "dimension" when you are creating an array identified by $item['month'] and let php decide last "dimension" key by []:

```
foreach($upcoming_data_arr as $key => $item) {
    $arr[$item['year']][$item['month']][] = $item;
}
```